# How to use web page caching on codeigniter based on user_agent?

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I want to use web page caching(Output caching) in my codeigniter application. My app serves different version of the page based on user agent(A version for mobile devices and other for desktop).

Currently when I cache output it saves the output based on how it is first accessed. And then serves the cached page to both desktop and mobile devices.

Is it possible to use two cached versions of a web page?
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html

Comment: Have you checked your cache directory and cached version of a particular web page? One more thing if your website/app is in responsive theme then by accessing your website each visited page will have a cached version(subject to caching applied on respective pages). Otherwise if you are providing two different views of the web page then CI will provide separate versions.

Comment: I have responsive design but still showing a version of the page to desktop visitors and a slightly different version to mobile. When I apply caching. It shows the same version on both desktop and mobile. If it's accessed from mobile browser first then it shows mobile version on both desktop and mobile. And if it's accessed from desktop first then it shows desktop version to both mobile and desktop. Is there a way to specify a separate cache directory in codeigniter for mobile and desktop pages?

Comment: Checkout if this helps https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/235693/#1053934